# Xamarin Forms pass parameter in viewmodel

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, parameter-passing

I am trying to create a Xamarin forms content page that contains a grid with an entry form, and then on the same page, a data grid containing the linked data.  So I have a surgical case and then the data grid will contain staff linked to that surgical case.  I am not sure how to link the staff data grid to the surgical case so that it only shows the staff from that one case.  I am including all of this in the same viewmodel.  How do I pass the SxCaseId from the entry form to the datagrid?

```
 public class SxCaseMasterViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ISxCaseDataService _sxCaseDataService;
    private ICaseStaffJoinForSxCaseDataService _caseStaffJoinForSxCaseDataService;
    private SxCase _selectedSxCase;
    private CaseStaffJoin _selectedCaseStaffJoin;
    private CaseStaffJoin caseStaffJoin;
    private ObservableCollection<CaseStaffJoin> _caseStaffJoins;
    private ObservableCollection<SxCase> _sxCases;

    public SxCaseMasterViewModel(IConnectionService connectionService,
        INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService,
        ICaseStaffJoinForSxCaseDataService caseStaffJoinForSxCaseDataService,
        ISxCaseDataService sxCaseDataService) : base(connectionService, navigationService, dialogService)
    {
        _sxCaseDataService = sxCaseDataService;
        _caseStaffJoinForSxCaseDataService = caseStaffJoinForSxCaseDataService;
        SxCases = new ObservableCollection<SxCase>();
        CaseStaffJoins = new ObservableCollection<CaseStaffJoin>();


    }

    public ICommand UpdateSxCaseCommand => new Command(OnUpdateSxCase);

    public SxCase SelectedSxCase
    {
        get => _selectedSxCase;
        set
        {
            _selectedSxCase = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SxCase> SxCases
    {
        get => _sxCases;
        set
        {
            _sxCases = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public override async Task InitializeAsync(object sxCase)
    {
        SelectedSxCase = (SxCase)sxCase;
    }

    public CaseStaffJoin SelectedCaseStaffJoin
    {
        get => _selectedCaseStaffJoin;
        set
        {
            _selectedCaseStaffJoin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CaseStaffJoin> CaseStaffJoins
    {
        get => _caseStaffJoins;
        set
        {
            _caseStaffJoins = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }




    private async void OnUpdateSxCase(object sxCase)
    {
        await _sxCaseDataService.UpdateSxCase(SelectedSxCase.SxCaseId, SelectedSxCase);
        OnPropertyChanged();
        await _dialogService.ShowDialog("Case details updated.", "Success", "OK");
        await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync<SxCaseViewModel>();
        //await _navigationService.PopToRootAsync();

    }

    public ICommand DeleteSxCaseCommand => new Command(async () =>
    {
        await _sxCaseDataService.DeleteSxCase(SelectedSxCase.SxCaseId);
        await _dialogService.ShowDialog("Case deleted.", "Success", "OK");
        await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync<SxCaseViewModel>();

    });

}



<ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Padding="10" x:Name="MasterGrid">

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>

                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Text="CaseId" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding SelectedSxCase.SxCaseId}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Label Text="Dos" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <renderers:SfDatePicker x:Name="dos" BindingContext="{Binding SelectedSxCase.Dos}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                    <Label Text="EyeId" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding SelectedSxCase.EyeId, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    <Label Text="Facesheet" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding SelectedSxCase.Facesheet, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
                    <Label Text="Record" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding SelectedSxCase.Record, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"/>
                    <Label Text="Complication" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"/>
                    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding SelectedSxCase.Complication, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"/>
                    <Label Text="ReturnOr" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6"/>
                    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding SelectedSxCase.ReturnOr, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6"/>
                    <Label Text="PhysicianId" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding SelectedSxCase.PhysicianId, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding SelectedSxCase.Physician}"/>
                    <Button Text="Update Case" Style="{StaticResource RegularButton}"
                                Command="{Binding UpdateSxCaseCommand}" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Button Text="Delete Case" Style="{StaticResource RegularButton}" 
                                Command="{Binding DeleteSxCaseCommand}" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>


                </Grid>



                <Grid Grid.Row="1">

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <RowDefinition Height="5*" x:Name="firstRow" />

                        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />

                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />



</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <datagrid:SfDataGrid 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding CaseStaffJoins, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="True">
                        </datagrid:SfDataGrid>




                </Grid>

            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: How about changing to a listview?  If needed you could have a grid in each element?  Or you could add an ItemTapped handler to each grid row.  (I know option 1 might be a bunch of rearranging)

Comment: if both are using the same VM, then they both have access to all of the VM data.  I'm not sure what you mean by "passing" data in this case.  Whenever the CaseID (or whatever) is updated in the Entry, then refresh `CaseStaffJoins` with the appropriate list of staff and the datagrid should update itself.